How to justify why we choose one type of simplicity and reject another type of simplicity?
When we reject a skeptical explanation, we need to explain and justify how we did it and why we made such a decision.
When choosing the best explanation, we must choose what is most important for us: induction and analogy or a small number of entities or simplicity of the explanation, etc.
How to do it?
When we reject solipsism, we need to show why we chose induction, analogy, unification, simplicity of explanation, and why we rejected the small number of entities, egocentrism, and special place in the universe offered by solipsism.
If we simply appeal to the opinions of philosophers or experts who say that a small number of entities does not make an explanation better and that a particular place in the universe is not a reasonable explanation, then it will be circular because we will be referring to other minds before we were able to justify the existence of other minds.
How to justify why the small number of entities that solipsism has is not a reason to believe in solipsism?
Should we refer to any of our observations?
thank you

+1 Was thinking something related to this earlier

My previous question was not answered. Therefore, I think that my other question will be answered.

Basically everything humans think is justified circularly. Sad but true. Some things seem better than others and that's how we decide, knowing that if we decide wrongly, reality will correct our errors. It's the result that matters, not how we arrived at it. So reasoning is never going to be as good as results.

In case you are worrying that solipsism is true, or that people around you may be philosophical zombies, pretty much no philosopher believes philosophical zombies are actually real in this world. Because they think there's a law of nature that makes anyone who is physically and functionally similar to you also have conscious properties (thoughts, feelings, emotions,...).
As for Occam's Razor, it can't be used to support solipsism, because:

Occam's Razor is about qualitative parsimony, it works in the number of type of entity, not its quantitative number. (See here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/simplicity/ . This article also covers justifications for qualitative parsimony). So the fact that solipsism postulates quantitatively less entities is irrelevant.
Occam's Razor is only useful when other things are equal. If two theories are equally good as each other, but one postulates less types of entity, then we should prefer that theory. But it's not clear that solipsism is equally good as non-solipsism theory with respect to things like explanatory power,... Hence other things aren't equal, and Occam's Razor can't be used here.

